# How to parse a char array into a double

Tags: c++

Here is my question, I created char temp[100] to store the numbers in a file, the `temp_i` is the index of current position(the numbers has `temp_i` digits)

How to convert the char array temp from 0 to `temp_i` into the `value` I created?

Can any body help me?

```
stack<int> first;
char temp[10]={'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
int temp_i = 0;
bool isDouble = false;
for(int index = 0; index< strlen(str); index++){
    if(str[index] != ' '){
      temp[temp_i++] = str[index];
    } 
    else if(str[index] == '.') {
      isDouble = true;
     } else {
       double value = *(double*)temp;
       cout<<value<<endl;
       first.push(value);
      }
}
```

Comment: "The numbers has temp_i digits".. hmm #grammar compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

If you allocated one more slot in your array and assigned it to '\0', you could treat your character array a C style string.

The C-style string opens up a whole bunch of library routines, such as [`std::strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) and [`std::sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) which can assist you.

You could also use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to get your double.

Comment: but I created a string, can it be converted into double?

Comment: You created an array of characters.  The primary difference is that C-style strings are terminated by a nul character.  Your array doesn't contain that.  I'm referring to `temp`.  You should use `strtod` on the `str` variable, which you didn't show the definition of.

Comment: e.g. char temp[11] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','\0'};

Comment: string value(temp, 0, temp_i);
      float n = ::atof(value.c_str());
the value is "4.5", but it parsed as 4 and 5, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

[Atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) (ascii to float) does pretty much exactly what you are trying to do.

It takes a pointer to a null ended string and returns a float.

You just have to cut your main string with all your numbers into one string per number, but that should be pretty easy with something like [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/).

Comment: string value(temp, 0, temp_i);
      float n = ::atof(value.c_str());

Comment: but the value is "4.5", but the output is 4 and 5 with a space between them

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the way you output your data.

How is it that you output it?

Answer (score 0):

Use sstream.

```
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char * str = "123.4567 813.333   999.11";
    stringstream converter;

    converter<<str<<str<<str;


    double number0;
    double number1;
    double number2;

    converter>>number0;
    cout<<number0<<endl;

    converter>>number1;
    cout<<number1<<endl;

    converter>>number2;
    cout<<number2<<endl;


    cin.ignore('\n', 100000);

    return 0;
}
```

Returns :

```
123.4567
813.333
999.11
```

Comment: Rather than using `getch()` and `conio.h` *(which are not standard)*, try using: `std::cin.ignore('\n', 100000)`.